# How to debug System Service on AOSP?

Tags: java, android-source, aidl

I wrote a simple system service that exposes the port 8545 on the localhost, but when I try to see if it runs, there is no open port.

Is there any way I can debug my System Service and/or gain insight into the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found an answer:

Just before the phone is booting you need to execute in the terminal `adb logcat`, once it boots it should show the logs.

But because there are so many logs you should pipe it into less, then a vim instance is started with all the logs:
`adb logcat | less`